# Como deve ser feito o backup perfeito do blog wordpress?

Tags: banco-de-dados, wordpress, backup, temas

Já faz um tempo que venho procurando na internet **como fazer backup do tema que estou desenvolvendo no wordpress e do banco de dados**.

Eu uso o `xampp` e o `banco de dados` no `phpMyAdmin`.

Eu encontrei diversos tutoriais, mas eu não estou sentindo segurança nesses tutoriais, **pois quero um backup completo**, com todas as configurações de plugins e todo o resto salvo, para que se um dia eu tiver um problema no site e eu perder tudo, eu possa pegar a ultima versão do backup e apenas coloca-lo no ar novamente. Sem grande esforço de procurar todos os plugins, fazer todas as configurações tudo de novo, pois apesar de eu ter pego um tema pronto, eu mudei muita coisa nele direto no php.

Quando digo backup perfeito, digo tudo, desde o banco de dados, plugins, posts, páginas criadas, configurações do tema, configurações dos plugins...

OBS: Estou usando o tema Oblique, segue o link:
https://wordpress.org/themes/oblique/

Como deve ser feito o backup desse modo? É possível? Se sim, por favor, me digam quais são as ferramentas que posso usar e como implementá-las?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Um "backup completo" do WordPress pode ser realizado guardando os seguintes dados:

- **Banco de Dados:** Os estarão as informações de seus posts, páginas, configurações do sistema e também de alguns plugins e temas.
- **Arquivos do Diretório:** Todos os arquivos que normalmente já vem na instalação padrão do WordPress (que como você informou, deve ter modificado) e também o diretório de temas e plugins.

Para realizar o backup do Banco de Dados, o próprio **phpMyAdmin** é uma boa alternativa, pois ele realiza a extração sem precisar ter muito conhecimento em `SQL`. Para os arquivos, qualquer cópia via **FTP** garante que seus dados estarão seguros localmente.

Se estiver lidando com mais de um site, e achar esse processo trabalhoso, recomendo utilizar uma plataforma de gerenciamento, como o **[InfiniteWP](http://infinitewp.com/)** ou o **[ManageWP](https://managewp.com/)**, por exemplo. Ambos facilitam esse processo de Backup dos sites para uma restauração rápida.

Comment: Felipe, o InfiniteWP ou o ManageWP, ele faz o backup do site(tema) + o banco de dados? Ou ele faz o backup só do tema WP mesmo?

Comment: Marcielli, conheço o InfiniteWP com propriedade para informar que ele realiza o backup completo (banco de dados + arquivos -- tema, plugins, etc ). Facilmente restaurável se necessário.

Comment: @FellipeSoares Cara tudo bem, seguinte estou tentando achar uma solução para fazer um backup completo de uma loja em wordpress/wooecommerce hospedada na hostgator e transferir para digitalocean, como se trata de um host compartilhado os recursos sao limitados vc sabe me dizer se esse InfiniteWP força muito o servidor podendo tirar o site do ar?   PQ eu nao to conseguindo por nada nesse mundo copiar a pasta wp-content do hostgator, nem o backup geral do site resolveu pois a pasta veio vazia.

Comment: @Erick, na configuração você define a quantidade de requisições que são feitas no servidor. Basta ajustar para algo que a HostGator aguente.